# Output values in multiple lines with same key in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I've got an example json:

```
{
  "queue_id": "ABCD12345",
  "sender": "sender@example.com",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "address": "recipient1@example.com"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient2@example.com"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient3@example.com"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient3@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get output that looks something like:

```
ABCD12345 recipient1@example.com
ABCD12345 recipient2@example.com
ABCD12345 recipient3@example.com
ABCD12345 recipient4@example.com
```

Starting with having sender address, currently i parse file to get the multiple queue_id for sender address, then with multiple queue_id I loop through them to get addresses, then loop through the addresses and then finaly getting other values from .json for current address/queue_id pair.
Is there a way to format this kind of output directly in jq or something easier than above mentioned double for loops?

**EDIT:**
more data

```
{
  "queue_id": "ABCD12345",
  "sender": "sender@example.com",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "address": "recipient1@example.com",
      "something": "output1"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient2@example.com",
      "something": "output2"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient3@example.com",
      "something": "output3"
    },
    {
      "address": "recipient3@example.com",
      "something": "output4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
ABCD12345 sender@example.com recipient1@example.com output1
ABCD12345 sender@example.com recipient2@example.com output2
ABCD12345 sender@example.com recipient3@example.com output3
ABCD12345 sender@example.com recipient4@example.com output4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
"\(.queue_id) \(.recipients[].address)"
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8i4od9GIDA)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
Could you point me to other thing also. I edited the data and using your example I can get also sender address "\\(.queue_id) \\(.sender) \\(.recipients[].address)", but when i try to get more from recipients[]  it multiplies output. I tried f.e. "\\(.queue_id) \\(.sender) \\(.recipients[].address) \\(recipients[].something)" and "\\(.queue_id) \\(.sender) \\(.recipients[].address, recipients[].something)"